# SQL Server AUDIT/event_time

Tags: sql-server-2012, audit

I am using SQL Server 2012 Audit and when I look through the captured events I can see that event_time does not show the correct time. Actually it shows 5 hours earlier than time on the server. Do you have any ideas how can I fix that ?

Answer (score 1):

The audit data uses UTC time. See [this link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/dcb4993a-2146-4980-9fa6-8beb6c2b1130/sql-server-audit-incorrect-event-time?forum=sqlsecurity) for suggestions to adjust your query.

> ```
> SELECT DATEADD(mi, DATEPART(TZ, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()), 'HERE goes your date')
> ```